# Output numbers without the parenthesis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

My input is a list of numbers:
[11, 5, 19, 7, 2, 7]

and output is an integer such as 30.

I need to format the output as follows:

11 5 19 7 2 7 (30)

I cannot have the bracket that shows that it is a list and I need parentheses around the output 30.

How can I format my output like the above?

Comment: Can you show the code you attempted to see where you are having difficulty? Could you also explain the significance of the `30`? Is this some type of calculation to come to `30`?

Comment: @idjaw, 30 is the output and the rest of the numbers are output. I need to format the my output like that where I need to put the inputs without commas and parenthesis and output in the parentheses by the side

Comment: For list you can just do print (*listvariable). Not sure what you meant with (30) though.

Comment: How does the output relate to the input?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to format the string like the following.

```
a = [11, 5, 19, 7, 2, 7]
b = 30
print(f"{' '.join(str(x) for x in a)} ({b})")
```

Hope it could help.